# How do i access a php file in a search query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Ok, so I'm making a somewhat simple search feature that connects to a MySQL server.
From my understanding the way to do this is to:

- Make a search page on the site.
- The search page will then accept a query and run it in the .php you provide
- A result page will come out.

This is the basic stock code i will use:

```
<html>
 <body>
 <form action="searchtemplate.php" method="post">
 Part ID: <input type="text" name="partID" />
 <input type="submit" /></form>&nbsp;

</body>
</html>
```

I got this from the w3 school site.. it's simple and it works.
The php file i'm using is:

```
<?php
/**
 Template Name: My Template
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="clearfix left-sidebar">

<!--BEGIN #primary-->
<div id="primary">

<?php the_post(); ?>

<?php $con=mysqli_connect("server","user","pass","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error(), mysqli_connect_errno());
  }

$part_query = $_POST['partID'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE part_id = $part_query"); 

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>part_id</th>
then rest of columns 

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['part_id'] . "</td>";
  then echo rest of columns

echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>"; 


mysqli_close($con); ?>


        <!--END #primary-->
        </div>

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div>

<?php get_footer();
?>
```

Ok, so I am using wordpress and I set this php up in the main theme directory and it can be accessed as a template. My main problem is that the search page appears fine but when I click submit it takes me to a blank page and not to the result page. I'd like to know if this is the correct way of doing what i am trying to accomplish or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is likely posting to the template, searchtemplate.php, and not a Wordpress page using the template to execute the code.

```
<form action="searchtemplate.php" method="post">
```

The "action" parameter in your form tag should point to the actual page on your site that is using your custom template.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is actually the case. If I can bother you for one more question: how would i input the next page in the action? I tried using a direct link and it still did not work for whatever reason.      EDIT: Sorry i hit enter by mistake and it made me post incorrectly, thank you though!

Comment: nevermind, stupid question. It works now! Thanks, man! I owe you one.